# Debugging pytest post mortem exceptions in pycharm/pydev

Tags: python, unit-testing, debugging, pycharm, pytest

I would like to use the built in Pytest runner of PyCharm together with the debugger without pre-configuring breakpoints.

The problem is that exceptions in my test are caught by Pytest so PyCharm's post mortem debugger cannot handle the exception.

I know using a breakpoint works but I would prefer not to run my test twice.

Found a way to do this in Unittest, I would like to know if something like this exists in Pytest.

[Is there a way to catch unittest exceptions with PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081343/is-there-a-way-to-catch-unittest-exceptions-with-pycharm)

Answer (score 13):

Are you using [pytest-pycharm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-pycharm) plugin? Looks like it works for me. Create virtualenv, `pip install pytest pytest-pycharm`, use this virtualenv at PyCharm `Edit configuration -> Python Interpreter` and then run with `Debug ...` Example:

```
import pytest

def test_me():
    assert None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main(args=[__file__])
```

PyCharm debugger stops at `assert None` point, with `(<class '_pytest.assertion.reinterpret.AssertionError'>, AssertionError(u'assert None',), None)`

### EDIT

Set  `Preferences > Tools > Python Integration Tools > Default test runner` to **py.test**. Then `Run > Debug 'py.test in test_me.py'`

Comment: It helped me! Thank you !

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810324/1870254) on how to make the debug console work with this!