# How to debug py.test in PyCharm when coverage is enabled

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, pytest

How do I debug py.test in PyCharm when coverage is enabled?

Coverage is enabled using `--cov=project --cov-report=term-missing`, removing this and breakpoints are hit.

Versions: pycharm 5.0.3, pytest==2.8.5, pytest-cache==1.0, pytest-cov==2.2.0, pytest-pep8==1.0.6, pytest-xdist==1.13.1, python-coveralls==2.6.0.

(thanks for jon's advice on further diagnosing the issue)

Comment: Could you give a bit more information about how you've set this up? I use PyCharm with py.test with absolutely no problems; running in debug mode gives the expected behaviour. Which versions, what configuration, how are you executing, etc. Also a [mcve] of the test and actual code might help.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Apparently the coverage plugin is causing issues, but it does usually work for me for non-py.test setups when using pycharm's default coverage? I'd give more info but I think this should now be reproducible.

Comment: I generally let PyCharm do the coverage, so it can do the fancy GUI stuff (line-by-line highlights, percentage by directory and file); run in debug mode for debugging (second run button or Ctrl-D) and coverage mode (third run button) when I want to run the suite for coverage. You could also set up separate configurations with and without coverage if you wanted.

Comment: This is a bug in PyCharm https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20186 https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-cov/issues/131

Answer (score 29):

There is now a [flag in py.test](https://github.com/kozmaz87/pytest-cov/commit/e391314f8a40041f134a195bf1d32651b275c2bd) to disable coverage which you can activate when running tests from PyCharm.

The flag to use is `--no-cov`. If you want this to apply to all your test runs you can add this to the default pytest configuration as below:
[image: Pycharm pytest debug]

Extra tip: You probably also want a `-s` flag in there so output isn't swallowed by py.test. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810324/238166 for details.

In case you receive an "unrecognized argument" error, you may need to install `pytest-cov`, e.g. by `pip install pytest-cov`.

Comment: This is only available in the professional version (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/product-tests.html) and can be found in the Run/Debug configurations (when you want to run your project)

Comment: You need to `pip install pytest-cov` first in order to pass in coverage-options!  Please consider updating your response for this @inti