# Debugging nosetest test in Pycharm doesn't show output

Tags: debugging, pycharm, nose

I'm trying to debug a test using nosetests in PyCharm. I need to stop at a breakpoint and do some interactive debugging using the PyCharm debug console. However, whenever I type anything at the debug console prompt, nothing is printed; I just get a new prompt. The debug console works perfectly with pytest, but I need to use nosetests for this particular test. How can I get the console to work correctly?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806099/pycharm-unit-test-interactive-debug-command-line-doesnt-work?rq=1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Most likely your nose runner suppressing stdout. Try running nosetests with `-s`

Answer (score 11):

Under the "Tools" menu, select "Edit Configurations."  In the dialog, expand "Python tests" and select the nosetests you are running.  Add "-s" as an "Additional Argument".

Comment: I assume you meant _Under the "Run" menu_

Answer (score 2):

Under the `Tools` menu, select `Edit Configurations`. In the dialog, expand `Python tests` and select the nosetests you are running. On the `Configuration` tab, under the `Nosetests` section, make sure the checkbox in front of `Params` is checked and then add `-s` as a parameter to it. `Apply` and `Save`.