# no output in console for unittests in pycharm 2017

Tags: pycharm, teamcity

I have created unitests using import unittest. When I want to run a specific test and I put a breakpoint then go to the console and try to eval expressions **there's no return value as if the stdout is no longer the console screen.**

I have never installed teamcity but strangely I do get messages when running the unittest. VERY STRANGE. I thought that maybe the **captureStandardOutput='true'** (emphasized on last line, below) is the cause of the problem but I can't even find where to change the param to test it.

```
C:\Users\selas\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 59641 --file "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1\helpers\pycharm\_jb_unittest_runner.py" --target tests.test_model.FigurationDBTesting.test_printFigurationPerBoundary
pydev debugger: process 8932 is connecting
Connected to pydev debugger (build 171.3780.115)

teamcity[enteredTheMatrix timestamp='...']
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest tests.test_model.FigurationDBTesting.test_printFigurationPerBoundary
teamcity[testSuiteStarted timestamp='...' locationHint='python://tests' name='tests' nodeId='1' parentNodeId='0']
teamcity[testSuiteStarted timestamp='...' locationHint='python://tests.test_model' name='test_model' nodeId='2' parentNodeId='1']
teamcity[testSuiteStarted timestamp='...' locationHint='python://tests.test_model.FigurationDBTesting' name='FigurationDBTesting' nodeId='3' parentNodeId='2']

teamcity[testStarted timestamp='...' >!> captureStandardOutput='true' <!< locationHint='python://tests.test_model.FigurationDBTesting.test_printFigurationPerBoundary' name='test_printFigurationPerBoundary' nodeId='4' parentNodeId='3']
```

Comment: You can try to edit ```helpers/pycharm/teamcity/unittestpy.py``` (in the PyCharm.app package on my Mac, not sure where it is for Windows). I changed it to ```captureStandardOutput='false'``` and the debugger starts with my modified value, but it's the same result :(

Answer (score 24):

Looks like the official fix for this bug, [PY-22505](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22505#u=1495640289685), is to add the new `JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING` environment variable to your unit test configurations (no value required, per screenshot), **but only for 2017.1.3 or greater**.

This screenshot shows adding the env var for the **Defaults** config, so all new configs will inherit it.  You could also add this individually to already-saved Run/Debug configurations:

[image: Setting env var for all future ad-hoc tests]

With that env var in place, I can now:

1. add a breakpoint
2. right-click any test or class and choose the **'Debug Unittests for ...'** menu option
3. hit breakpoint, go to debug console
4. inspect my runtime and get the printouts (note `captureStandardOutput='true'`):

   ```
   ...
   ##teamcity[testStarted timestamp='...' captureStandardOutput='true' locationHint='python</Users/zyoung/PycharmProjects/Foo/test/unit_tests>://test_distance.Foo.testMatchRatio_050' name='testMatchRatio_050' nodeId='3' parentNodeId='2']
   import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
   Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 12:39:47) 
   [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

   >>> print(self)
   testMatchRatio_050 (test_distance.Foo)
   ```

Comment: @KarelMacek Which version of PyCharm do you have?

Comment: In fact, I did not add that variable to already existing tests.

Comment: This works for me:
`PyCharm 2017.2.3`
`Build #PY-172.3968.37, built on September 1, 2017`
`JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b11 x86_64`
`JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o`
`Mac OS X 10.12.6`

Comment: Is there a way to set this setting globally?  ( Works for me in 2017.2.4 )

Comment: @Pekka, did you see the paragraph and the screenshot regarding **Defaults**? I think that will address your "global" needs.

Comment: @ZacharyYoung it seems that the defaults in run configurations are defaults by project. So I have to set this setting in all projects separately. tbh  it's not so big deal but I was looking for a place to set this globally for multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be because you use pycharm 2017.1 combined with a python environment that has teamcity-messages in it? That combi crashes, see 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23926

Upvote that ticket if that's the case please (making an account took me 1 min).

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue running pytests for django in the Pycharm debugger. Adding `-s` as a parameter did the trick for me. As seen in the Pycharm bugreport: [PY-22505](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22505#u=1495640289685) from Zach's answer.

Answer (score -1):

[Pycharm unit test interactive debug command line doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806099/pycharm-unit-test-interactive-debug-command-line-doesnt-work)

use pytest

(Run > Edit Configurations > Defaults > Python tests > py.test > add -s to the options field------>(Additional Arguments).)

settings default run tests by pytest:

(Preferences > Tools > Python Intergrated Tools > default test runner)