# Pycharm debugging console outputs ##teamcity

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, teamcity

I can see the following output when using pycharm / intellij debugger console. Any suggestions how to solve this are appreciated.

Unittests and Nosetests (same attribute error appearing in different forms)

UNITTESTS:
[image]

And the end of the very long string is:
nAttributeError: |'FlushingStringIO|' object has no attribute |'encoding|'|n|n'

NOSETEST: 
[image]

Comment: Duplicate, but can't flag it as the other doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078352/pycharm-debug-console-unreadable-because-of-teamcity

Comment: The latest version of intellij seems to solve the problem