# Can PyCharm drop into debug when py.test tests fail

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

When running tests with `py.test` there is a `--pdb` option to enter pdb on failure.

Is there a similar way to enter the debugger when running the same test from within PyCharm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging pytest post mortem exceptions in pycharm/pydev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086067/debugging-pytest-post-mortem-exceptions-in-pycharm-pydev)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a py.test plugin, [pytest-pycharm](https://github.com/jlubcke/pytest-pycharm), that will halt the PyCharm debugger when a test emits an uncaught exception.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! Can you give a couple of words on how it is working?.. By just being installed in Python and without any modifications to projects?

Comment: It is enough to have it installed so that py.test finds it as a plugin an use the callback when an exception is encountered. So there is no need to modify any project apart from having it installed in the python runtime.

Comment: Is there a way to stop on breakpoints (set in tests from within PyCharm)?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using `pyenv`, as it uses shell-script shims to wrap python programs such as `pytest`, and his means that PyCharm is not directly running a Python program, so cannot engage the debugger.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, at least not when I simply select 'Debug [mytest]'.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below to setup the correct run configuration:

1. Run > Edit Configurations...
2. Click the '+' button to add a new configuration.
3. Name the configuration and specify the configuration parameters below:

**Script**: The path to your py.test executable (find by typing `which py.test`)

**Script Parameters**: This parameter is your test case followed by the `--pdb` option (ie `/Users/Johan/projects/misc/testing.py --pdb`)

After setting up the configuration, you can run the test case from within PyCharm.  If a test case fails, your PyCharm run window will show the pdb prompt.

[image]

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough in my question, but I was hoping for a way to enter the _PyCharm_ debugger on failure. But this answer is still better than nothing.

Comment: In PyCharm 2016.2, I see "entering PDB" in the Run window, and I can type text (echoes in green), but it does not seem to be an active pdb prompt.