# `pytest-pycharm` not stopping on test failures for PyCharm 2019.2

Tags: pycharm, pytest

The `pytest-pycharm` package is suppose to allow PyCharm to drop into a debug exception breakpoint on a test failure (as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24382282/1191087)). This has worked successfully in the past. However, in PyCharm 2019.2 (possibly earlier) it seems to no longer be working (the test simply fails and outputs the failure to the console).

I'm not sure if this is due to the new PyCharm version or the package versions (or something specific in my setup). What might be a solution to this problem?

`pytest` version 5.0.1, `pytest-pycharm` version 0.5.0. `pytest-cov` is not installed, and adding `--no-cov` fails as an unexpected argument (this has been a [solution for somewhat similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40906766/1191087)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*pytest-pycharm* not working with PyCharm 2019.2 is a known issue – [Incompatibility with PyCharm 2019.2](https://github.com/jlubcke/pytest-pycharm/issues/14). In the console output you should see the following error

> INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: 'PyDB' object has no attribute
>   'handle_post_mortem_stop'

This issue was [fixed](https://github.com/jlubcke/pytest-pycharm/pull/15) in version 0.6.0.